# Need To Set Limits For Scroll Event In JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am using a scroll event but would not like the user to be able to scroll past the node in site. I have tried the following but the issue is that I cant scroll back up once it is reached

Code:

```
        label.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
            @Override 
            public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
                    label.setTranslateY(label.getTranslateY() + event.getDeltaY());
                    System.out.println(label.getTranslateY());
                    if (label.getTranslateY() <= -2370)
                    label.setOnScroll(null);
                    }
            });
```

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: It is because when you reach that point `-2370`, it removes the `setOnScroll` event.

Comment: Yes, but how can I set it to not allow it to scroll beyond that point without removing the event? @HypnicJerk

Comment: If you remove the `setTranslateY()`, will the label move? If not, move that code within your `if` statement and check `label.getTranslateY() > -2370`, this way it will only move if its greater than that location. Also, remove the `setOnScroll(null)`

Comment: @HypnicJerk Now it is stopping when I get to that point but still won't let me scroll back up

Answer (score 0):

```
public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
    double newY = label.getTranslateY() + event.getDeltaY() ;
    if (newY > -2370) {
        label.setTranslateY(newY);
    }
}
```